# Errors by using align

Tags: align

I have the following code, which generates 4 errors (all of the type "bad math environment delimeter") but I don't know why.

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[fixamsmath,disallowspaces]{mathtools}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}      
     P_U (t) &= - P_{EZ_1} (t) - P_{EZ_2} (t) - ... - P_{EZ_n} (t) - P_{V_{ges}} (t) \\
   P_{EZ_{ges}} (t) &= P_{EZ_1} (t) + P_{EZ_2} (t) + ... + P_{EZ_n} (t) = \(\sum \limits_{i=1}^n {P_{EZ_i}} \\   
     Z_1 &= \(\sum \limits_{t=0}^T Z_1(t) 
    \end{align*}



\end{document}
```

Comment: You can not use `\( \)` inside the `align`. Is is used to change to math mode (as `$ $`) but it is already in math mode.

Comment: Also, please use `\dots` instead of `...`. `amsmath` will detect which dots should be used.

Answer (score 2):

You can not use `\( \)` inside the `align` environment. It is used to change to math mode (as `$ $` does) but your code inside `align` is already in math mode.

Also, as commented by @Paul, don't type the dots (`...`) directly from keyboard. There are commands to do that. Use `\dots` from the `amsmath` package and the 3 dots will be inserted on the right place. Compare the examples below:

```
$a_1,\dots,a_n$ and $a_1\times\dots\times a_n$
wrong: $a_1,...,a_n$ and $a_1\times ... \times a_n$
```